# Capture everything but the last 3 digits

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, substring

I need to capture the value of a number without the digits. Let's say I need only 17 from 17,873. The number can also be without comma, like 17873. How can I do that with AMPscript substring? A round down will work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easily.  YOu get the length of the string and then use substring based on length minues your number:

```
%%[

SET @num = "17,873"
SET @length = Length(@num)
SET @final = SubString(@num, 1, Subtract(@length, 4))

]%%
```

That should do it.

If you are looking to do it based on variable, you can likely use IndexOf() on the comma (Indexof(@num, ',') and then use that instead of the subtract() function)

e.g.

```
%%[

SET @num = "17,873"
SET @index = IndexOf(@num, ',')
SET @final = SubString(@num, 1, Subtract(@index, 1))
/* Subtract by one to remove the comma itself from displaying */

]%%
```

Comment: Small typos... I think there's a missing closing bracket of the SubString functions

Comment: You are correct, edited answer to include these.